# Is there a way to send notifications from firebase when a database value equals a certain value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I was wondering if there is a way to send a notification to a specific user when a value in their account's database node has a child with a certain value?
Eg:

- User-1009ag5443C6a5

  - Friends: 12

I would like it so that if friends is <= 10, the user gets a notification alerting them of a milestone of 10 or more friends.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup Firebase Cloud Messaging in your app using your existing firebase account, the official guide is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). **Each installation of app** gets a unique token, as you will find in the guide. This token will need to be sent to server and stored in db, to send messages to that particular user-app instance.

You can then display a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) when a message is received in your app.